# Detect Smiley and Globe when selected in iOS 8 keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, keyboard

I need to be able to detect when the user selects the smiley and globe on the iPhone and iPad keyboard so I can resize my view based on if predictive text is supported. 
I have tried myUITextView and keyboard delegates but no luck there. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

You want to listen for the `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` notification.

The userInfo dictionary contains information about the keyboards frame, animation duration and curve.

With this info, you can then uplate your UI to move any views out the way if needed etc.

More Info: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html

Answer (score 0):

If the use selected globe or emoji, your keyboard will be dismissed. Why you need to know?

edit: sorry I though you are building third-party keyboard